# Change Integromat module ID

Tags: make.com

Let's say you have **module1** that is linked to **module2**. You decide **module1** is the wrong type of module. Perhaps it is watching Mailchimp subscribers rather than getting a specific subscriber.

You delete a **module1** and replace it with a new one, **module3** that does what you want.

Unfortunately, **module2** is looking for data from **module1** with a *module ID* of 1.

All of your data mapping will have a "1." prefix.

If you want **module2** to work with the new **module3**, it looks like the only way to do that is to manually change all the mapping.

You would think that you could just change the *module ID* of **module3** to "1" but I don't see how you can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Recently, Integromat restricted the *Export/Import* functions to paid users only. If you're on the free plan, there's no easy way to do what is asked.

---

You can change the ID of a module through the blueprint file. Here's how:

[image]

1. Find this menu in the toolbar below in the Scenario Editor.
2. Export the blueprint. You will be downloading a JSON file to your computer.
3. Open the file in a text editor.
4. Find the line that says `"id": 3,` and replace it with `"id": 1,`. This changes **module3**'s ID to be 1.

   - If you didn't delete **module1** before exporting blueprint, you can delete it and start from *step 1* with a new blueprint. Otherwise, a viable shortcut is to find the *other* `"id": 1,` and replace it with `"id": 3,`. That way the IDs of the two modules are swapped and there's no conflict. (This shortcut could be useful if you want to keep both modules available and need to swap between them from time to time.)
5. Save the file and import it using "Import Blueprint".
6. Check that the import was successful - the module ID in the Scenario Editor should be updated. *Remember to save your scenario!*

   - If you see reference warnings, they should disappear once you click on the modules with warnings to check. Or try refreshing.